# Call external python script running different version

Tags: python

7, but also need to use libraries that I have installed on a different version of python - 3.7

My main script runs with python 2.7, from which I need to pass some parameters to a separate python script which requires python 3.7

Is this feasible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the pickle module to save the parameters from the 2.7 script and then load the pickle object in the 3.7 script.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html